# ffmpeg - adding/re-encoding audio stream on video file

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming

I want to add an audio stream to an existing video file. The issue I have is that:

- File can have more than 1 audio stream (different languages/commentary).
- File can have more than 1 text stream.

My problem is that sometimes the audio codec is not compatible with my media player, so I simply want to copy "X" audio stream (usually DTS), convert it to AAC and add it to the same file.

I've tried some examples from [this forum](https://superuser.com/questions/811939/ffmpeg-convert-and-keep-audio-track) but I've mixed results. Especially because of the txt streams.
I'm sure there's a way of getting this output in one go.

Is this the right command?

```
ffmpeg -i "input-video.mkv" -map 0:v -c:v copy -map 0:a -c:a copy -map 0:1 -c:1 libfdk_aac -b:a 384k -map 0:s -c:s copy "output-video.mkv"
```

Where:

```
-map 0:1 -c:1 libfdk_aac -b:a 384k
```

Means map file 0, stream1, copy...  and then I don't know what it's doing

I have also added output of ffmpeg -i "input-video.mkv"

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input-video.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : input-video
    encoder         : libebml v0.7.7 + libmatroska v0.8.1
    creation_time   : 2008-09-18T20:25:36.000000Z
  Duration: 02:23:27.34, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 12303 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x800, SAR 1:1 DAR 12:5, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      title           : Commentary
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: ass (default)
    Stream #0:4(eng): Subtitle: ass
    Metadata:
      title           : Commentary
    Stream #0:5(cze): Subtitle: ass
    Stream #0:6(dan): Subtitle: ass
    Stream #0:7(fre): Subtitle: ass
    Stream #0:8(ger): Subtitle: ass
    Stream #0:9(hun): Subtitle: ass
    Stream #0:10(nor): Subtitle: ass
    Stream #0:11(pol): Subtitle: ass
    Stream #0:12(por): Subtitle: ass
    Stream #0:13(rus): Subtitle: ass
    Stream #0:14(scc): Subtitle: ass
    Stream #0:15(scr): Subtitle: ass
    Stream #0:16(slv): Subtitle: ass
    Stream #0:17(spa): Subtitle: ass
    Stream #0:18(swe): Subtitle: ass
```

Comment: Need to see output of `ffmpeg -i "input-video.mkv"`

Comment: @Gyan, output added as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want two copies of the audio stream, one as original DTS, and one as AAC, map the stream meant for re-encode first.

`ffmpeg -i "input-video.mkv" -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a -map 0:s -c copy -c:a:0 libfdk_aac -b:a:0 384k "output-video.mkv"`

Comment: Thanks, these seems to work. Although I tried in a different file which doesn't have subtitle streams and got an error, fixed by using:
`ffmpeg -i "input-video.mkv" -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a -map 0:s? -c copy -c:a:0 libfdk_aac -b:a:0 384k "output-video.mkv"`
I think this solves my problem thx again